# graph algorithm, approximation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, approximation

After removing the leaves of the dfs tree of a random graph , suppose the number of edges left is |S|, can we prove that the matching for that graph will be |S|/2?

Comment: By |S|/2 you mean floor or ceiling?

Comment: 1)Is |S| the number of edges after removing the leaves of the DFS tree or the original random graph?
2) By matching you mean the maximum matching or any matching is ok?

Comment: @kunigami 1) |S| is after removing the leaves of DFS tree 2) any matching which is maximal will do so any matching will do. To correct my question, it is ceiling(|S|/2) instead of just |S|/2.

Comment: Ok, now I understood. So I think Keith Randall answered your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof.

Theorem: Let `T` be any tree with `i` leaves.  There is a `(|T|-i)/2` matching in `T`.

Proof: by induction.  If `T` is a tree with `i` leaves, let `T'` be the tree that results when removing all the leaves from `T`.  `T'` has `j <= i` leaves.  Similarly, let `T''` be the tree that results when removing all the leaves from `T'`.  `T''` has `k <= j` leaves.

Apply the theorem by induction to `T''`, so there exists a matching of size `(|T''|-k)/2 = (|T|-i-j-k)/2` in `T''`.  The set of edges `T-T'` contains at least `j` edges that are not incident to any edge in `T''` or to each other (pick one incident to each leaf in `T'`), so add those edges to make a matching in `T` of size `(|T|-i+j-k)/2`.  Since `j >= k`, this is at least `(|T|-i)/2` edges. QED.

I've glossed over the floor/ceiling issues with the /2, but I suspect the proof would still work if you included them.